# Get minutes between two ISO format time in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I need to get minutes between to ISO format date in java/kotlin
Example :
Need to know minutes between below two iso times

> 2019-02-18T06:37:00.000Z
>   2019-02-18T11:46:00.000Z

Comment: Did you try to convert those `String` to `Date` then get their timestamp and divide it by 1000 * 60?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle that leads huge steps i'm afraid

Comment: You mean to get the amount of time between those two, in minute or the difference in minute between the two. ?

Comment: @AxelH Difference in minutes sir

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) and `toMinutes()` method:

```
ZonedDateTime dt1 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-02-18T06:37:00.000Z");
ZonedDateTime dt2 = ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-02-18T11:46:00.000Z");
System.out.println(Duration.between(dt1, dt2).toMinutes()); // 309
```

Comment: Good Answer, except that `Instant` would me more appropriate that `ZonedDateTime` as no time zone is indicated, only an offset-from-UTC of zero (or UTC itself). The `Z` at the end means UTC, an offset of zero. In contrast, a time zone is a name in the format of `Continent/Region` such as `America/Montreal`. Example: `Duration.between( Instant.parse( "2019-02-18T06:37:00.000Z" ) , Instant.parse( "2019-02-18T11:46:00.000Z" ) ).toMinutes()`